# vbscript : registry directories and keys listing

Tags: vbscript, registry

If I have a registry pathing of:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INTERSTAR\XFILES\CONFIG MANAGER\SYSTEM\COMPANIES
```

How would I go about listing all the records under that path/directory and access the DWORDs, REG_SZs and data?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to use WMI:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
    Wscript.Echo subkey
Next
```

You will find more useful registry scripts here: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/operatingsystem/registry/

Comment: In fact I'm not aware of any *other* way to do Registry enumeration within Windows script. None that would work without installing third-party dependencies beforehand at least. +1

Comment: Actually I'm neither aware of any other way, although it seems a little strange that there isn't a more "native" way to do it.

Comment: If you look at it strictly, there is next to nothing you can do with "native" VBScript. The language was build to use COM objects extensively and painlessly, so you could say that using a COM object *is* the native way of getting things done in VBScript.

Comment: Yes, true. But since COM still is *the* component model of Windows one would expect to have COM objects available for basic things such as registry access. WMI seems rather heavy-weight for that job...

Comment: Oh, that. ;-) You are right, I always wondered myself why they never made a registry pendant of the FileSystemObject. Would not have been too hard, I guess.

Comment: Powershell is the more *native* way to do it IMO. This line would do it in PS: GCI "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\INTERSTAR\XFILES\CONFIG MANAGER\SYSTEM\COMPANIES"

Comment: Having said tht however, this answer is the right one for VBS. +1